# PHP/JavaScript: How to encode/decode strings best?

Tags: javascript, php, string, encoding, decoding

I need to encode a string with Javascript and would like to decode it with PHP (code below).

Unfortunately the usual functions like `urlencode()`, `encodeURIComponent()`, etc. will not work in this case, because my PHP framework interprets slashes `/` as separators, even the encoded ones.

The string length is in a range of 1 to 50 chars. Encrypting isn't the focus, rather performance.

Does anyone know a good alternative to `base64`?

**Javascript**

```
var str = doEncode("I'm a String with special chars!§$%&/()");
window.location = "http://localhost/script.php?encoded_string=" + str;
```

**PHP**

```
$str = doDecode($_GET["encoded_string"]);
echo $str; // I'm a String with special chars!§$%&/()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Solution: *fix* the "PHP framework". Your making up a solution to a problem that doesn't [need to] exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with user2864740

Or you can use Base32 
since you have only 50.

Answer (score 0):

Well, perhaps [php bson](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bson-decode.php). Read more at [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/). Its popularised or used by MongoDB but maybe check it out for alternatives to `basexxx`